# Function to retrieve entries from sql db within certain number of days from current day

Tags: php, sql

I'm writing a function that retrieves all entries in one of four specific columns that fall within a specified date range from the current date. IE. the columns contain expiry dates and I want to be able to show entries that are expiring within 30,60,90 days from the current date. I'm having a little trouble getting it right any help you can offer I would greatly appreciate. Also please don't give me the prepared statements and PDO lecture, I'm well aware of it and the need for it but this is not for external consumption so sql injection is not an issue and over complicating this would be counter productive for me.

Here's what I have so far.

```
// list_entries_set function lists all entries expiring in the next $days
function list_entries($days) {
    if(!$days) $days = "365";

    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $end_day = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_day)) . " + '.$days.'day");

    db_connect();

    $orderby = $_GET["orderby"];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column BETWEEN ".$today." AND ".$end_day."  ORDER BY ".$orderby);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "table outputs : purged because it's irrelevant and lengthy";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    db_disconnect();
}
```

Comment: "sql injection is not in issue for me" Are you kidding? Especially because prepared statements (beside the security issue) makes things _simpler_. Also: `ext/mysql` is outdated, not maintained anymore and is flagged as deprecated with PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: If you truly believe SQL injection is not an issue, you need to go back to CS 101, not ask on here.

Comment: this is an INTERNAL application that is not internet facing and will be used by 2 people so no I truly believe SQL injection is not an issue...

Comment: I think I already mentioned not to give me the PDO lecture, I have a reason for saying that

Comment: @alexboorman There are no reasons. They simply don't exists. The smallest argument is, that you write your application with `ext/mysql`. Would you write an application for Windows95? I don't think so ;)

Comment: Still hoping to find an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL :duration DAY LIMIT ORDER BY :order;
```

Use a prepared statement-capable engine to resolve the placeholders. `ext/mysql` is not an option anymore.

Comment: I don't do this for a living, its basically a glorified excel spreadsheet converted to a web app. It's not for public consumption and I don't know object oriented programming So learning a completely new coding methodology to accomplish a fairly simple task seems counter intuitive to me? If you want to help me with my original question feel free but I already said I'm not interested in a PDO or MySQLi oriented solution to this multiple times.

Comment: @alexboorman No offense, but in 2013 you never heard of OOP (independent from PHP)? Regarding your question: You should be able to simple extract from my answer, what you need (it is a simple query with just 2 placeholders ;)). But I for myself don't feel comfortable in providing answers covering 90th-style coding.

Comment: I know what OOP is but I don't use it because as I said this isn't an occupation for me. I'm not a programmer I'm an illustrator, I just know what I know I don't doubt that learning OOP would broaden my horizons but I just don't have a need to learn some completely complex new way of doing things just to accomplish a simple task when it's not certain I'll ever use it again. I also don't understand why you'd spend so much time criticizing the way I'm doing it when I've made it clear I have my reasons for doing it that way!

Answer (score 0):

The sql for entries that expire within 30, 60, or 90 days from the current date would be something like this;

```
select item
, case when datediff(expiry_date, current_date) <= 30 then 'within 30'
when datediff(expiry_date, current_date) <= 60 then 'within 60'
else 'within 90'
end whatever_you_want_to_call_this
from your_tables_joining_if_necessary
where expiry_date >= current_date
and expiry_date < date_add(current_date, 91, days)
```

The syntax might not be correct for mysql.  I don't work with it and was simply looking at the manual.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but this looks pretty foreign to me. I'm not sure that this wouldn't work in some incarnation but I don't know how to go about using it